# HorizontalScrollView - need to scroll by width of the images

Tags: android

I have a HorizontalScrollView that consists of Images (Icons).  I need to scroll the view in "blocks" the width of the icons, so as to never have a "piece" of the icon on the screen.  I need more, but this question will give me all the other answers I need.

Does anyone have a code example to point me to for this?

Thank You in advance.

JS

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a [`Gallery`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) or create your own custom `View` that does this (maybe extend `HorizontalScrollView`).

Comment: Gallery does not quite act as I really need it to.  Thank you for the advice, I had looked into using it previously.  Given thought and a bit of number crunching, my posted method works wonderfully (and you did mention overriding HorizontalScrollView - which I had partially done).

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this in two parts.

I dynamically add the buttons from resource files and account for spacing on the left, right, and between.

I modified HorizontalScrollView to simply scroll to one of X positions (whichever is closer to the currently stopped position).

Again, thanks for reading.

JS